# How to convert a timestamp (DATE FORMAT) to BIGINT in SQL

Tags: sql

I need to convert the timestamp value (Format: `2012-11-19 14:29:50.0`) to a `BIGINT` value (Format: `2012111315041650` = `YYYYMMDDhhmmss`). I need to insert current time in a column of a table which accepts only `BIGINT`.

I am using Squirrel SQL Client Version 3.3.0. The query I am using right now is

```
INSERT INTO table1 (BINGINT_DATE, TIMESTAMP_DATE) 
VALUES (2012111315041650, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Instead of manually entering the `BIGINT_DATE` value, I want to convert the `CURRENT_TIMESTAMP` or `NOW()` to a `BIGINT` value as the format `YYYYMMDDHHMISS`

Something like

```
INSERT INTO table1 (BINGINT_DATE, TIMESTAMP_DATE) 
VALUES ("CONVERT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP,BIGINT)", CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Let me know if it is feasible to do this way

Please help me with this.

Thanks

Comment: ***SQL*** is just the *Structured Query Language* - a language used by many database systems, but not a a database product... many things are vendor-specific - so we really need to know what **database system** (and which version) you're using....

Comment: How you get 20121113150416 explain :)

Comment: `20121113150416` ins't a format. Do you mean `YYYYMMDDhhmmss`? I ask because that does not match your first example of `2012-11-19 14:29:50.0`... Also, why would you want it in this format? Why not `Seconds since Epoch` or something similar? Then atleast the *number* would actually *mean* something. Rather that trying to use a BIGINT as a pretend string...

Comment: 20121113150416 value is manually entered in integer format. 2012-11-19 14:29:50.0 need to be converted into YYYYMMDDhhmmss format.

Comment: @developer1: Squirrel SQL is just the **client** you're using - that's not really helpful. We need to know what **database backend** you're working against!

Comment: @developer1 try to run this `SELECT @@SERVICENAME ServiceName, @@VERSION VersionInfo` What do u get? Errors or ServiceName, VersionInfo?

Comment: Which DBMS are you using? Oracle? PostgreSQL? DB2? Firebird?

Comment: 6 upvotes? I smell something fishy.....

Answer (score 2):

For Postgres you can use:

```
INSERT INTO table1 (BINGINT_DATE, TIMESTAMP_DATE) 
VALUES (to_char(current_timestamp, 'yyyymmddhh24miss')::bigint, CURRENT_TIMESTAMP);
```

Answer (score 1):

To convert timestamp values to bigint values (in seconds) you can do it in this way:

```
SELECT (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2019-04-02T14:56:39.009'))::bigint -- -> 1554216999
```

To convert timestamp values to bigint values (in millis) you can do it in this way:

```
SELECT ((EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM TIMESTAMP '2019-04-02T14:56:39.009'))::numeric * 1000)::bigint -- -> 1554216999009
```

If you want to convert all timestamp values of a column into a table into another column of the same table you can run this query (result in millis):

```
UPDATE $table_name$ SET $column_with_values_bigint$ = (EXTRACT(EPOCH FROM $column_with_values_timestamp$)::numeric * 1000)::bigint
```

Hope this help.

Answer (score 0):

For Oracle: Use `to_char` and `to_number` functions as below

```
    TO_NUMBER(TO_CHAR('2012-11-19 14:29:50.0', 'YYYYMMDDHHMISS'))
```

For MySQL: Use `DATE_FORMAT` & `CONVERT` as below:

```
  CONVERT(DATE_FORMAT('2012-11-19 14:29:50.0'', '%Y%M%d%H%i%s'), UNSIGNED BIGINT)
```

Comment: You've assumed the RDBMS.  This is ***not*** a universal answer.  Would you care to specifiy which RDBMS this is and is not valid for?

Comment: I am new to databases. I am using Squirrel SQL Client Version 3.3.0.
The query I am using right now is 
INSERT INTO table1 (BINGINT_DATE, TIMESTAMP_DATE)
VALUES (2012111315041650,CURRENT_TIMESTAMP):
Instead of manually entering the BIGINT_DATE value, I want to convert the CURRENT_TIMESTAMP or NOW() to BIGINT value as er the format YYYYMMDDHHMISS

Answer (score 0):

The following will give you what (I think) you are after:

```
DECLARE @TM VARCHAR(50) = '2012-11-19 14:29:50.0'


SELECT (CAST(SUBSTRING(@TM,1,4) AS INT) * 10000000000)
     + (CAST(SUBSTRING(@TM,6,2) AS INT) * 100000000)
     + (CAST(SUBSTRING(@TM,9,2) AS INT) * 1000000)
     + (CAST(SUBSTRING(@TM,12,2) AS INT)* 10000)
     + (CAST(SUBSTRING(@TM,15,2) AS INT)* 100)
     + (CAST(SUBSTRING(@TM,18,2) AS INT))
```

However there may be a better solution to the overall problem which others have mentioned, if you give some more details we might be able to suggest a less dirty alternative.

Answer (score 0):

you can try something like that on MS SQL:

**From bigint to datetime:**

```
select dateadd(s, convert(bigint, '<bigint value like 1477958400000>') / 1000, convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00'))
```

**From datetime to bigint:**

```
select cast(datediff(s, convert(datetime, '1-1-1970 00:00:00'), convert(datetime, '<datetime value like 11-01-2016>')) as bigint)* 1000
```

Cheers

Answer (score 0):

DATETIME to BIGINT;

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, FORMAT(CURRENT_TIMESTAMP, 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'))
```

OR

```
SELECT CONVERT(BIGINT, FORMAT(GETDATE(), 'yyyyMMddHHmmss'))
```

BIGINT to DATETIME;

```
SELECT CONVERT(DATETIME, FORMAT(20191220213340, '####-##-## ##:##:##'))
```

Answer (score -1):

Sql Server; Replace `GETDATE()` With your `Column name`

```
SELECT CONVERT(bigint,
       CONVERT(VARCHAR(12) , GETDATE() ,112) +  
       REPLACE(CONVERT(VARCHAR(8) , GETDATE() ,108),':',''))
```